# Volumetric error when rendering mantaflow fire simulation

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation, error, fire, mantaflow

so I've been working on honing my fire-simulation skills in the Cycles renderer using Mantaflow as I'm set to be using it soon for a project; but while working on looks and so on, I noticed a render error that I've not come across before.

If you look at the fire itself, the edges have these "blocky" outlines, its most noticeable along the leftmost border of the fire, here is appears as dark blocky borders to the fire, but its also visible at the back end of the fire, where the block is brighter than the backdrop[image]

[image: Fiery car with volumetric render error very noticable on especially the left side]

The error like stated above, is very obvious and basically ruins the whole thing: it might be worth mentioning that the fire simulation is emitted via a particle system and not mesh.

Is anyone able to tell me how I would go about removing these blocky almost "bounding-box"-like artifacts.

Comment: Hello, even if the error is obvious, take a moment to describe your issue with detail, the more info you put, the better for the users to help you.

Comment: I can see your problem there., Are there any actual cuboids there that might be set to a volumetric material, and are appearing in the render?

Answer (score 0):

"I can see your problem there., Are there any actual cuboids there that might be set to a volumetric material, and are appearing in the render?" - ZargulTheWizard

Yes, thats it! It seems my volumetric node for the fire wasnt set to an absolute black, making the actual cuboids themselves only semi-transparent.